# Help with limiting output

Tags: list-manipulation, output

I wrote this program on Mathematica (which I am very new to):

```
h[n_] := n + n/FactorInteger[n][[-1, 1]] + 1
L = NestList[h,1,10]
Do[Do[If[MemberQ[L, NestList[h, y, 10][[x]], Print[y, " ", x]],{x, 1, 10}],{y, 1, 10}]
```

(This code may not be particularly efficient, but it's the best I know how to do.) Which basically calculates how many iterations of `h` must be applied to `y` to reach an element of `L`.

When I run the program, I get:

$$1~1$$
$$1~2$$
$$1~3$$
$$1~4$$
$$1~5$$
$$1~6$$
$$1~7$$
$$1~8$$
$$1~9$$
$$1~10$$
$$2~3$$
$$2~4$$
$$2~5$$
$$...$$
$$10~2$$
$$10~3$$
$$10~4$$
$$10~5$$
$$10~6$$
$$10~7$$
$$...$$

(There should be spaces between the numbers)
You can see that the program prints ten values for every `y`. It probably requires rewriting of the entire program, but I would like to tell it to only print the first value of `y`, so the above list would become:

$$1~1$$
$$2~3$$
$$...$$
$$10~2$$
$$...$$

The values are probably all under 5, but it is possible that there are some greater than 10. I would also like to remove that limit.

I have no idea how to do this, because I do not know Mathematica well enough yet. I would appreciate help with this very much. Thanks.

P.s.: To help clarify, these are the first few values of the output as I would like them to appear, which I have calculated by hand:

$$1~1$$
$$2~3$$
$$3~1$$
$$4~2$$
$$5~1$$
$$6~2$$
$$7~1$$
$$8~2$$
$$9~1$$
$$10~2$$
$$11~2$$
$$12~3$$
$$...$$

And no, I do not want to save this as a list, unless it can be kept in the above format.

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, then you just need to add the conditional operator around the `Print[***]`. Something like If[y==1,Print[***]]

Comment: Do you really just want to print this to the screen? Would you rather have the values saved to a list?

Comment: @Cody H. If you would like to merge these two accounts, please contact a moderator.

Answer (score 2):

```
h[n_] := n + n/FactorInteger[n][[-1, 1]] + 1
L = NestList[h, 1, 10]
h[n_] := n + n/FactorInteger[n][[-1, 1]] + 1
firsts[max_Integer] := Module[{L = NestList[h, 1, max]},
  Prepend[FirstPosition[NestList[h, #, max], a_ /; MemberQ[L, a]], #] & /@ Range[max]
 ]
firsts[10]
(* {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 2}, {7, 1}, {8, 2}, {9, 1}, {10, 2}} *)
```

Since you insist on that output format:

```
ToString[#1] <> " " <> ToString[#2] & @@@ firsts[10] // Column
```

[image]

or, better:

```
TableForm@firsts[10]
```

[image]